# Draw textual PHP graph

Tags: php, graph, charts, linechart

I need to draw a line chart using PHP which fullfills the following requirements:

- Textual X-Axis descriptors
- Not every serie has values for all X-Axis values
- Markers on the given points

I have already detailed watched pChart, JpGraph and LibChart, but I didn't manage to get the expected result. It should look like this (poorly drawn with MsPaint):

[image: The requirements for my Chart]

**EDIT**: The exact problems:

- With Libchart, I didn't manage to get different series with not all x axis values filled
- With pChart, there was the same problem (e.g. at the above example, pChart would not make a line at the blue series from desc 3 to desc 6, when values 4 and 5 have the value `VOID`). I could also calculate the values between, but then they would also have markers (e.g. at desc 4 and desc 5)
- With JpGraph, I didn't manage to create textual x axis values

Thank you for your help, Community!

Comment: What was the actual problem using any of the libraries you mentioned, they should all be capable of doing this, as should others like Graphpite

Comment: @MarkBaker I've edited my question. Maybe some minor things, but I didn't manage to find some exact answers to my problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using pChart:

I can use `VOID` for points which do not have an own value, and set a config setting like the following one:

```
 $myPicture->drawLineChart(array('BreakVoid'=>false,'VoidTicks'=>0));
```

Using this settings, VOID will draw correct lines to the next known value.